# CSS transform property with calc

Tags: css, css-calc

I want to make a calculation for the transform property.
Is it possible to use the **calc** feature for that?

Something like:

```
 width: calc(100vw-2vw);
```

but for transform

```
 transform: translate(calc(100vw-2vw));
```

(Of course the above is not functional)

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't know why it shoulden't work.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't see that before. Here is something useful for other people who will see my duplicate post [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150054)

Comment: @Vinc199789 I tried but it is not working. You can see the above link.

Comment: @BillysGtr okay. Nothing is animation but I get the div chaged position. What I did is I removed the prefixes for the calc. (Do not remove them for the transform. they need prefixes). Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJUEv/11/. You can also take a look at this site:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc . If this work say it and I will post this a a anwser so than can you close the question

Comment: Thanks @Vinc199789. I read the link from mozilla and _GCyrillus_ gave me a great answer. Your comment is helpful too. It says that:  The + and - operators must always be surrounded by whitespace. 
The * and / operators do not require whitespace, but adding it for consistency is allowed, and recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you respect a white space in between calc values and signed used : `transform: translate(calc(100vw` `-` `2vw));`

```css
div {
  border:solid;
  float:right;
  height:20vw;
  width:20vw;
  transform:translate( calc(-100vw + 25vw) );
}
```

```html
<div><p>Do not forget !<br/>use prefix if needed !!!</p><p>BTW, i float right</p></div>
```

Comment: Wow...super answer!! Thanks! Wired that thing with the white space!